# Create directory in Java but don't throw error if it already exists

Tags: java

So, I want to create a directory in Java. In case of the directory already existing that function would do nothing and won't throw an error, but if it doesn't exist, it would create one. Does such a function exist in Java?

Comment: Might be mistaken, but it sounds like you're just looking for a try-catch where nothing happens on the catch?

Comment: The accepted answer should have you covered.  If not, drop a comment and someone can reopen the question.

Comment: Hmm, you mean to have FileAlreadyExistsException and do nothing inside it.

Comment: Alternatively you could use [Files.createDirectories(Path dir, FileAttribute<?>... attrs)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#createDirectories(java.nio.file.Path,%20java.nio.file.attribute.FileAttribute...)) which will not raise an exception if the dir already exists. It differs in that it would lead to the creation of the parent dirs were those not to exist. (actually its use is covered in the second most upvoted answer of the linked duplicate)

Comment: I've found the solution. I can just use File.mkdirs.